# Agile different methodologies

Tags: android, mobile, agile, desktop-application

I know very little about Agile but I wonder if there is any difference in methodology between mobile applications and desktop/web applications?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about methodologies. programmers.stackexchange.com or pm.stackexchange.com may suit methodology questions better - but do show some research effort in the question there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between mobile app et web app agile management.

You can find different docs :

- [Agile Development Methods for Mobile Applications](https://publish.inf.ed.ac.uk/publications/thesis/online/IM100767.pdf)
- [A case study](http://drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/193501924)